# Can't edit input after switching focus with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, input, focus, backspace

I'm experiencing this issue on several Android devices, using JS to switch the focused field.
- While I'm inserting value, everything is going well, so once a field has reached the max-length, then the "next" field is being focused;
- On the other hand, when I try to use backspace to clear the field (using below code), in several devices, the focus seems to be changed to previous field, but I can't write anything in it.

```
$('.AllMyFields').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if( e.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
        _prevField = ... the previous field selector ...

        if( _prevField.length > 0 ) { 
         _prevField.get(0).focus()
        }
    }
});
```

If I manually tap on the field, then it will work;
Any idea?